# Sharepoint REST API filter eq with value containing % in Value

Tags: rest

I am trying to fetch a record using the Sharepoint REST API, where the property Title contains a % in the actual value. And sharepoint REST API always returns empty value.

Example : 
If my Title value is **'10 Percent'** ... the below query works.

```
_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('CompletionStatus')/items/?$filter=**Title eq '10 Percent'**
```

If my Title value is **'10%'** ... the below query returns empty.

```
_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('CompletionStatus')/items/?$filter=**Title eq '10%'**
```

Is there any way to escape % for comparing to fetch the record?

I need % to be used in the Field Value in my real application and use eq for comparing values.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tired %25 ? this is the url encoding escape code for %